# How to you use json schema in ajax

Tags: ajax, json

i have trying connecting json to ajax with this source code, but i don't know why this source code doesn't work any idea?

this is source code:

```
    var my_JSON_object = {};

var http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
http_request.open("GET", url, true);

http_request.onreadystatechange = function ()
{
  var done = 2, ok = 100;
  if (http_request.readyState == done &&
      http_request.status == ok) {

    my_JSON_object = JSON.parse(http_request.responseText);
  }
};
http_request.send(null);

i hope someone can give me a solution.

var my_JSON_object = {};

var http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
http_request.open("GET", url, true);

http_request.onreadystatechange = function ()
{
  var done = 2, ok = 100;
  if (http_request.readyState == done &&
      http_request.status == ok) {

    my_JSON_object = JSON.parse(http_request.responseText);
  }
};
http_request.send(null);
```

Comment: _'this source code doesn't work'_ is not a problem description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy way is use jquery - then your ajax code can be as simple as

```
$.post("ajax_directory/yourfile.php",
    {para: para, parb: parb, parc: parc, pard: pard, pare: pare},
    function(data) { what you want to do with the data )."json");
```

If you put that final "json" in you can even have the returned data in json format and sent  it to different items on the page according to their id.

The para etc are variables you have set and the whole thing can be wrapped in a response to a button click, select change, keyup etc